# imacro load url every 10 loops

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops, imacros

i have created this simple imacro code and i am set it to 99999 loops (using imacro extension for firefox)

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 150
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>Video
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=42
```

but the page sometimes needs reload.Can you please tell me how i can set the code to reload the page every 10 loops for example?
When this code reach to loop number "10" i want to load page "http://www.google.com" for example.
When this code reach to loop number "20" i want to load again this page.
When this code reach to loop number "30" i want to load again this page.
Every 10 loops the page will reload and this goes "forever"!
I would be glad if you can fix the code, i think its not that hard, but i really have no idea in imacros!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste this code

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 150
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>Video
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=42
```

10 times and add

```
URL GOTO=www.google.com
```

at the end of it. I will do example with 3 times copy and then adding this URL command.

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 150
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>Video
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=42
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 150
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>Video
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=42
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 150
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:View<SP>Video
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=42

URL GOTO=www.google.com
```

I also recommend using JavaScript scripting.

Comment: Clever answer, i tried it and runs smoothly.Thank you very much for your help.Yes maybe javascript is better but i have no idea how to use it!Thanks again!

Comment: Np. Just mark my answer as the best since that is the best way to thank me. :)